# How can I bundle assets by `rollup.js` when I use `url()` to import an img?

Tags: vue.js, components

As title, I use `url()` to import an img in my Vue component. But when I run `yarn build`, after building, img file cannot be found in target dir.

eg.

```css
.background {
  background-image: url('./img.jpg');
}
```

All component JavaScript code has been bundled in target dir, but the `img.jpg` cannot be found in target dir.

Comment: Try using full path from your root directory by using ~ symbol. ```background-image: url(~assets/images/your_image.jpg)```. If not worked give more detail about your folder structure where images located.

Comment: background-image: url("~assets/images/your_image.jpg)"); should work